# Loop led to Error: 'SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame'

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

Aim: To fill NaN values of rainfall stations by taking the rainfall value of the nearest neighbouring station.

Dataset: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12Hhg9rMoCisFkMVeLIOajdCZ5nL2iFKgEERViww9nqg/edit?usp=sharing

I attempted to do a loop in which I will access the gdf by date, fill the NaN values of a rainfall station with another nearby station (that is not a NaN as well) until all rainfall stn values for the date are filled. I will then move on to the next date and fill all the NaN. I will then output this to a csv that has all the NaNs filled.

However, upon running it, I am facing an error: "SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame." when I clearly did not use any '.copy()' in the code.

Thank you so much for your kind help!

Code:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


### Print options
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)

### Load data
datafr = pd.read_csv('Comb_Daily_Pr_Special.csv')

### Station geodataframe
Stn_data = pd.DataFrame(datafr,columns=['id','Longitude','Latitude'])
Stn_data_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(Stn_data, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(Stn_data.Longitude,Stn_data.Latitude), crs='EPSG:3414')

### Re-make Precipitation array to [id,Date,Rainfall,Stn_name]
dfr = datafr.melt(id_vars=["id","Station","Longitude","Latitude","Elevation"], var_name="Date", value_name="Rainfall (mm)")

### Join gdf and dfr by 'id'
gdf = pd.merge(left=Stn_data_gdf, right=dfr, how='outer',on='id' )
gdf = gdf.sort_values(['Date','id']).reset_index().drop(columns=['index','Longitude_x', 'Latitude_x', 'Elevation','Longitude_y', 'Latitude_y'])
#df.to_csv('final.csv')

### Applying multi-indexing - FINAL Dataset for filling NaNs
gdf.set_index(['Date','id'], inplace=True)

### Get index of stations with NaN rainfall
nan_rainfall_idx = gdf.index[pd.isna(gdf['Rainfall (mm)'])] #tuple index that has nan rainfall

### Loop attempt at filling NaNs
for idx in nan_rainfall_idx:
    year_idx = idx[0]
    stn_idx = idx[1]
    point = gdf.loc[idx].geometry

    s = gdf.loc[year_idx].geometry

    for i in range(len(gdf.loc[year_idx])):
        if (s.distance(point).argsort().iloc[i] > 0) and (pd.notna(gdf.loc[year_idx].iloc[s.distance(point).argsort().iloc[i]]['Rainfall (mm)'])):
            closest_stn_posindex = s.distance(point).argsort().iloc[i]
            closest_stn_rainfall = gdf.loc[year_idx].iloc[closest_stn_posindex]['Rainfall (mm)']

    gdf.loc[idx]['Rainfall (mm)'] = closest_stn_rainfall

print(gdf)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it would be rather hard for me to quickly dig into your code with details, I assume your bottleneck is here where you try to assign values to a chain-indexed `gdf`:

```py
gdf.loc[idx]['Rainfall (mm)'] = closest_stn_rainfall
```

There is the [explanation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing) in pandas docs. I'm not sure what was the expected behaviour of your code, but I could pass this warning by indexing with another way like this:

```py
gdf.loc[idx, 'Rainfall (mm)'] = closest_stn_rainfall
```

Comment: Hi sir, thank you so much for your help, I followed your 2nd '.loc' instruction and was able to run the program with no error. But, it is running and takes forever with no output. Tried checking online for hours but I'm still not able to find a resolution for this. Really need your help on this.

Comment: @Saqif I took a look into your `gdf` and found that there are around 500000 missing values. If your loop is correct it iterates over not only that number of indices but it looks through multiple other rows each time — therefore it may take quite a long time. If you add a printout within your loop (and you may shorten the range of nan indices too when testing) you'll see what's going on there and if it's doing what you meant it to do. Given so much data to process, have you considered using e.g. `.fillna(method='ffill')`, in case the data is sorted by time and distance?